Кириллические синонимы языков программирования
По-моему, синонимы с, си, питон не нужны. Их надо убрать!

почему ты думаешь, что синонимы не нужны?

@αλεχολυτ, а зачем вопрос закрыл?

@Qwertiy так в плашке написано зачем

Эти синонимы не нужно убирать. Синонимы добавлены, чтобы никто не мог добавить кириллические варианты меток.

@αλεχολυτ, не вижу причин, по которым в вопрос надо что-то добавлять.

@Qwertiy в вопросе нет обоснований предлогаемому действию, это как минимум.

@aepot, для обоснований есть ответы.

@Qwertiy представь вопрос вида "Давайте снимем ромб у Qwertiy". Это весь содержательный текст. Что ты сделаешь с таком вопросом? Напишешь ответ?

@Qwertiy тыжмодератор. Если считаешь нужным, переоткрой, дай ответ.

Можно переформулировать в "Зачем нужны кириллические синонимы". Кому-то это действительно может быть непонятно.

Синонимы нужны потому что:

Если их не будет, то рано или поздно всё равно кто-то создаст метку на кириллице, только она уже не будет связана с правильной.
При печати вопроса и поиске может быть удобнее искать метку на русском.
В случае с некоторыми языками, например, c и c#, отличить написание на русском от написания на английском визуально невозможно.

